# Trying to launch Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) through ConEmu and provide additional commands

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu

I have a service I want to run with the "make run" command in WSL via a new task in ConEmu. Right now I have in the commands section:

-new_console:d:C:\pathtofolder\folder wsl

How do I add on the "make run" command to be run AFTER WSL has launched in that folder? Currently when I try to add make run to the end of that, it tries to make in bash, not WSL.

Comment: Have you read docs? https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartCmd.html and https://conemu.github.io/en/BashOnWindows.html

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure I understand them properly. I have tried to add arguments or parameters to the above command, but I can't seem to get the correct format or something. The errors aren't specific either and just say I did something incorrectly.